# Using iOS Network Extension Framework API to find out the status and name of the VPN on the iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, vpn, nevpnmanager

I've gone through some posts already on Stack Overflow, but I did not find a proper answer any where. Here are my questions:

1) Our app uses Cisco AnyConnect app for VPN on the iOS devices. Will I be able to use the network extension framework API (like NEVPNManager) classes just to find out the status and name of the (connected or disconnected) vpn on the iOS device programmatically or is it just supposed to be used only for programmatically custom created VPN connections in iOS?

2) Can I use the same API to find out the information (status, VPN name etc) of all the different VPN connections existing on the device (say if I have 2 VPNs under "VPN Configurations" section and 3 Personal VPNs)?

3) To use the network extension framework API (like NEVPNManager) classes, do I need to send an entitlement request to Apple? or just generating/downloading the VPN config and Control provisioning profile enough?

4) Finally, can I use the API to create a custom VPN for my app and have it use the Cisco AnyConnect VPN app's implementation?

Comment: Hi @iOSNinja, do you manage to find out the answer to your questions? I have similar issue as you

Comment: @shoujo_sm, here are the answers i received in my email from the author (Mohammad Mahdi Ramezanour) of this blog (http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/), for my questions: Answers: 1 and 2) As far as I know, you won't be able to other VPN status or names or anything else. Apple won't let you access those informations. 3) No. If you're not going to develop a custom protocol, then all you need is to just enable network extension feature in the iTunes connect.